# Mongoose Saved _id'ss as a string instead of ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Nodejs with Mongodb and Mongoose.

I just found out that Mongoose/Mongodb has been saving the auto generated _id field as a string as opposed to an ObjectId. Mongodb shell output and sample documents:

```
> db.users.count({_id: {$type: 7}})
2
> db.users.count({_id: {$type: 2}})
4266

> db.users.find({_id: {$type: 7}},{_id:1}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f7df6fdb8aa078465ec6ec") }
> db.users.find({_id: {$type: 2}},{_id:1}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : "558c3472c8ec50de6e560ecd" }
```

The 4266 _id's (strings) come from this code:

```
var newUser = new ApiUser();

newUser.name = name;
newUser.link = link;
newUser.signupTime = new Date().getTime();
newUser.initialBrowser = initialBrowser;

newUser.save(function(err) {
     if (err)
          res.json(err);
     else
          res.json('success');
});
```

and the 2 _id's (ObjectId's) come from this code:

```
var newUser            = new User();
newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id;
newUser.facebook.token = token;
newUser.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
if (profile.emails) {
    newUser.facebook.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();    
}
newUser.facebook.gender = profile.gender;
newUser.facebook.profilePic = profile.photos[0].value;

newUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        return done(err);

    return done(null, newUser);
});
```

User() and ApiUser() both reference the same model. The one that saves ObjectId's is in a Facebook authentication Strategy with Passport.js

UPDATE: here is my user schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    link: Number,
    location: String,
    residence: String,
    age: Number,
    gender: String,
    subject: String,
    signupTime: Number,
    finishTime: Number,
    shared: String,
    search: String,
    shareFriend: String,
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String,
        gender       : String,
        profilePic   : String
    },
    interestsSummary: [Number],
    interests: [{name: String, iType: String}],
    valuesSummary: [Number],
    values: [{name: String}],
    traitsSummary: [Number],
    traits: [{name: String}],
    bio: String,
    friendInterests: Number,
    friendValues: Number,
    friendPersonality: Number,
    surveyLength: String,
    missedInfo: String,
    anythingElse: String,
    finalBrowser: String,
    consented: Boolean

}, {collection: "users"});

// generating a hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The issue is that I can't seem to query mongodb based on the ones that are strings, which is giving me problems:

```
        ApiUser.findById(req.body.friend,{name:1},function(err,user) {
            console.log(user);
        })
```

This returns null unless I search for one of the 2 users with a proper _id. Req.body.friend is the _id, which is a string. How can I either change all the document's _id's to ObjectId's, or query the existing documents with string _id's?

Comment: Please show your schema and a sample document. And please list the sample document as shown in the mongodb shell rather than node console output, as the former will correctly display the type information.

Comment: Schema and sample document posted. Also, I apologize. The output was from the MongoDB shell.

Comment: The most logical case here is that the schema has been changed or some  other code is the cause of this. Mongoose needs two specific settings in order to have written strings in any way, and certainly not an ObjectId as a string. You should just be able to convert the string values to `ObjectId` with some simple scripting. If there is any code doing this, it is not the code you are pointing at.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured out the issue. Posted it below if you're curious

Comment: Is there any problem in having this as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty specific question, but if anyone happens to stumble upon a similar issue, my problem was that I wrote a file with all my documents as a json to use mongoimport on a remote server.

The issue was that JSON.stringify() will convert an objectId to a string. To fix it I wrote just wrote a small script to loop through all the objects in my users array and convert all _id's back to objectId's with the following command:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
user._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(users[i]._id);
```

Then calling Model.create() on my mongoose model with the updated documents to bulk insert, and deleted the original documents