# Change mongoose column from object to ObjectId

Tags: mongoose, schema, objectid, oid

I'm facing a strange issue where some records in my database have been saved  as a classic object, instead of an ObjectId.

Here is an example of bad entry:

[image]

How it should be:

[image]

Can someone explain why those records have been saved that way, even though my userId schema type is `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`? How can I make them ObjectId?

Comment: Please add your schema and you code where you `save` to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Made it work, based on this answer: [Mongoose Saved _id'ss as a string instead of ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619699/mongoose-saved-idss-as-a-string-instead-of-objectid)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
user._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(users[i]._id);
```